# How to make list of tests and run only them?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso, android-testing

I have lots of Expresso tests (as you know, it is slow tests). When I'm investigating some problem I only need run small list of them. List contains tests from different test classes.

Is it possible to make this list in Android Studio and run them at once by small count of clicks?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get this done using JUnit TestSuites. 
Create a class with all test classes you want to isolate and test.

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClass({
    //.......,
    //your test classes here,
    //........
})
public class MyTestSuite {
}
```

You can run these directly from MyTestSuite or from command line.

```
./gradlew app:connectedDebugAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=your.package.name.MyTestSuite
```